# How to hide/show on toggle and hide on clicking outside the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div which when clicked shows a `contact us` form .
That is, on toggle it shows and hides. How can I make it to hide on clicking from  other part of document.

The code is below

```
 function showCctFrm(){
    var frmWidth = '-40';

    $("#quick_cct_form").toggle(function(e){
        if($("#quick_cct_form").is(":visible")){ frmWidth = "200"; }
        if($("#quick_cct_form").is(":hidden")){ frmWidth = "-40"; }

        $("#fixed_cct_us").css("right",frmWidth+"px");
        //e.stopPropagation();
    });
    //alert(frmWidth);
}
```

**I tried this to hide on clicked outside:**

```
 $(document).click(function(e) {
  if(e.target.id != 'fixed_cct_us') {
    $("#quick_cct_form").hide();
    $("#fixed_cct_us").css("right","-40px");
  }
});
```

the HTML div for that is as below

```
<div id="fixed_cct_us" style="right: 240px;">
    <a title="connect" href="javascript: showCctFrm();">connect &nbsp;</a>
</div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403615/use-jquery-to-hide-a-div-when-the-user-clicks-outside-of-it

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** Insert a quick DEMO.

```js
$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
    var container = $("#quick_cct_form");

    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0)
    {
        container.hide();
        $("#fixed_cct_us").css("right","-40px");
    }
});
```

```css
div {
  
  width: 500px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 30px auto;
}

form {
  background: red; 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

input {
  margin: 20px;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
<form id="quick_cct_form">
  Edit: <input type="text" placeholder="CustomerId" />
</form>  
</div>
```

The Snippet:

```js
$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
    var container = $("YOUR_SELECTOR");

    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0)
    {
        container.hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').on('mouseup', function (e) {
  $("#quick_cct_form").hide();
  $("#fixed_cct_us").css("right","-40px");
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

**updated code below**

```
$(document).on('mouseup', function (e) {
      $("#quick_cct_form").hide();
      $("#fixed_cct_us").css("right","-40px");
      e.stopPropagation();
    });
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/v87kx4bm/)

Comment: didnt hide on clicked from outside :(

Comment: Outside where? If the body is being clicked and the target item is not the form, then the form should hide. Where are you clicking?

Comment: Now;the code                                $("#quick_cct_form").toggle(function(e){
        if($("#quick_cct_form").is(":visible")){ frmWidth = "200"; }
        if($("#quick_cct_form").is(":hidden")){ frmWidth = "-40"; } 

        $("#fixed_cct_us").css("right",frmWidth+"px");
        //e.stopPropagation();
    });is not working ;the toggle is only able to open the form not able to close the form